# Pie chart Vega LITE - Labels position

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

_Hi, for each slice, in the middle of its angle, I try to left align labels outside the circle almost like :[image: This try]

Seems to be simple, but I struggle to obtain a nice result for the whole labels after many tries...
Here is the link of my file :
https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv6mUvq5650jFGm1hH?e=XbJ2d1

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update

[image]

```
{
  "width": 230,
  "height": 220,
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "Conso_A_Plan_Clé",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "stack": true
    },
    "order": {
      "field": "Conso_A_Plan_Clé",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": "descending"
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Destination",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {
        "field": "ORDER",
        "order": "descending"
      },
      "legend": null,
      "scale": {
        "scheme": "pbiColorNominal"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "******RING BACKGROUND GEN COL******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "outerRadius": 60
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "******Name labels******",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": {
          "expr": "scale('theta', ((datum.Conso_A_Plan_Clé_end - datum.Conso_A_Plan_Clé_start)/2) + datum.Conso_A_Plan_Clé_start ) > PI  ?95:65"
        },
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dy": 0,
        "fill": "black",
        "align": "left",
        "text": {
          "expr": "[datum.Destination,format(datum.Conso_A_Plan_Clé,'.1f')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! almost. I need to align left & verticaly labels like "PRI" & "124,7" for example.

Comment: I'll update now.

Comment: Seems to be nice! Couldn't have found the code...
To improve the clarity of the chart, is it possible to adjust the position of "COM & 44.7" (in order to not to be stuck to RIE label) ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: The minor adjustments are difficult because you have left aligned the text and so it depends on the text length and the theta of the pie slice. I'm not sure I could improve the solution without lots of specific rules for individual slices.

Comment: It's perfect ! Thanks a lot ! So pro...

Comment: Thanks for the HowTo ! I've juste upvoted all the comments...

Comment: Not the comments lol - the solutions :D

Comment: Very odd : I checked your answer with the (green) check mark on the left of your answer. I can't see any other chek location on the screen ?